# how to prove my approximation ratio?

Tags: algorithm, approximation

suppose we are given a weighted graph G and we want to cluster its nodes into k clusters such that sum of weights of all edges between clusters be maximum. we want an approximation algorithm of ratio (1-1/k).

my solution : cause this is a maximization problem,first of all we must find an upper bound for OPT solution. let k be n and G is a complete graph so the OPT will be sum of all edges and its the maximum value we can reach to. so OPT <= SUM(all edges). the approach is described as :

if k = n  the solution is trivial if k < n we consider all n node as a disjoint set and find the minimum weighted edge and union disjoint sets of two nodes which are connected through this edge. we repeat this procedure until number of disjoint sets equals to k.

at the end we have removed at least (n-k) low weighted edge (in this case our result equals to OPT) and at the worst case only (k-1) high weighted edge has been remained to bee added into the result.
at this case result is Sum(k-1 high weighted edge). to prove that our approach has approximation ratio (1-1/k) we should show that (1-1/k)Sum(All) <= Sum(k-1 high weighted edge). I doubt this is correct or not.can any one help me to prove it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving homework it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let V1, ... , Vk be an initial random clustering on V with the same sizes.
Now, it is sufficient that for each u in Vi and v in Vj with

W(u,Vi)+W(v,Vj) > W(u,Vj)+W(v,Vi)

move u to Vj and move v to Vi.

Now, we have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zeTI.png

Answer (score 0):

Please let `k=2` and then, run your proposed solution on the following graph :

```
G=(V,E) 

V={a,b,c,d} 

E={({a,b},2) , ({a,c},3) , ({a,d},1) , ({b,d},2000000) , ({c,d},2000000)}
```

Comment: in this example we have 2 cluster, one {a,d,b} and the other {c} and the result is 2000000+2000000+3 which I think its OPT in this case

Comment: No, if we have 2 clusters {a,d,b} and {c}, the result is 2000000+3 which is not OPT. I think the optimum solution is {a,b,c} and {d}; in this case, the result is 2000000+2000000+3.